# Number of connected components of the complement of a compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

Let $X$ be a connected, locally compact space and let $K$ be a compact subset of $X$. Is the number of connected components of the complement $X\setminus K$ finite?
If it is not, are there some hypotheses over $X$ for finiteness of connected components?

Comment: What've you thought so far?

Comment: I have studied Ends of topological spaces, It is defining by inverse limit process over the inverse system of $\{\pi_0(X-K): K\subset X\quad\mbox{is compact}\}$. I wanted understanding when this sets is finite because the Ends is a subspace of $\Pi_{K} \pi_0(X-K)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose $X = \mathbb{R}$ and let $K$ to be the Cantor set. Then $X \setminus K$ has infinitely many connected components.

Comment: Thanks for your counterexample! For my purposes I will need add more hypothesis.